# Java: set.remove() method doesn't remove the object from Set

Tags: java, set

I am making a small mistake I think while trying to remove an object from the set in the `forEach()` loop. The `remove()` doesn't remove the object, can anyone point out what the issue could be? Thanks!

```
Set<RoleExtEntity> roleExtEntitySet = roleEntity.getExt(); //set size = 3
Map<String, RoleExtEntity> roleExtEntityMap = 
        new HashMap<>(roleExtEntitySet.size());

roleExtEntitySet.stream().forEach(roleExtEntity -> {
      if (role.getName() == null && roleExtEntity.getKey().equals("name")) {
            //this line doesn't work; set size should be 2 but it's still 3
            roleExtEntitySet.remove(roleExtEntity);
      } else {
            roleExtEntityMap.put(roleExtEntity.getKey(), roleExtEntity);
      }
});
```

Comment: Have you checked the return value of [`Set.remove(Object o)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#remove-java.lang.Object-)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> can anyone point out what the issue could be

Without seeing your code, I'd guess that it's because you're not overriding `equals` and/or `hashCode` correctly, and/or you have modified `roleExtEntity` since it was put into the map in a way that affected the `hashCode`.

Irrespective, if this `remove` actually *did* work, you would risk a `ConcurrentModificationException`, because you are removing from the collection you are iterating.

You can instead do this with an explicit `Iterator`, which allows you to `remove()`:

```
for (Iterator<RoleExtEntity> it = roleExtEntitySet.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
  RoleExtEntity roleExtEntity = it.next();
  if (...) {
    it.remove();
  } else {
    // ...
  }
}
```

An alternative could be to split up the `forEach` into something doing the removing, and something doing the putting:

```
if (role.getName() == null) { // Since role appears to be unchanged in the loop
  roleExtEntitySet.removeIf(roleExtEntity -> roleExtEntity.getKey().equals("name"));
}

Map<String, RoleExtEntity> roleExtEntityMap =
    roleExtEntitySet.stream().collect(
        Collectors.toMap(RoleExtEntity::getKey, r -> r));
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! Really appreciate it. This works :)